# How Can i Update only one Column of SQL Table via store procedure with passing rest column value null

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is What i Have tried.
I Have created a Table [tblUser] which allow null value and a Store procedure [spUpdateUser] with All Parameters which can be passed null except ID parameter

Whenever this procedure executes it will only update the passed (Not Null) Parameters

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblUser]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FatherName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DOB] [date] NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateUser]
@ID int,
@UserID varchar(50) = null,
@Name varchar(50) = null,
@FatherName varchar(50) = null,
@DOB date = null
AS
BEGIN
update tblUser set
    UserID = @UserID,
    Name = @Name,
    FatherName = @FatherName,
    DOB = @DOB
    where ID = @ID
END
```

How can i update table [tblUser] with only passing one parameter

```
exec [spUpdateUser] @ID = 1, @DOB = '27 Mar 2017'
```

Comment: Does `Name`, `FhaterName` and `DOB` allow nulls in your table schema?

Comment: Yes But I Want Other Column value to be Untouched on Update Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `COALESCE` between the passed in parameters and the existing values.

When the passed in value is `NULL`, the query will retain the existing values.

This will, however, make it difficult to update to `NULL` if you do actually require the Nulling of these values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateUser]
@ID int,
@UserID varchar(50) = null,
@Name varchar(50) = null,
@FatherName varchar(50) = null,
@DOB date = null
AS
BEGIN
update tblUser set
    UserID = COALESCE(@UserID, UserID),
    Name = COALESCE(@Name, Name),
    FatherName = COALESCE(@FatherName, FatherName),
    DOB = COALESCE(@DOB, DOB)
    where ID = @ID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateUser]
> @ID int,
> @UserID varchar(50) = null,
> @Name varchar(50) = null,
> @FatherName varchar(50) = null,
> @DOB date = null
> AS
> BEGIN
>
>     UPDATE tblUser
>     SET    UserID = COALESCE(@UserID, UserID),
>            Name = COALESCE(@Name, Name),
>            FatherName = COALESCE(@FatherName, FatherName),
>            DOB = COALESCE(@DOB, DOB)
>     WHERE  ID = @ID;
>
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dbo.tblUser VALUES (1, 'John', 'Father John', '20180101');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> EXEC dbo.spUpdateUser @ID=1, @FatherName = 'My Father';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tblUser;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | UserID | Name | FatherName | DOB                
> -: | :----- | :--- | :--------- | :------------------
>  1 | 1      | John | My Father  | 01/01/2018 00:00:00
> ```

> ```
> EXEC dbo.spUpdateUser @ID=1, @DOB = '20180105';
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tblUser;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | UserID | Name | FatherName | DOB                
> -: | :----- | :--- | :--------- | :------------------
>  1 | 1      | John | My Father  | 05/01/2018 00:00:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=066bb253240d18a70517bc40c7840809)*